# Bash curl and variable in the middle of the url

Tags: bash, curl

I would need to read certain data using curl. I'm basically reading keywords from file

```
while read line
do
    curl 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'"${line}"'/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json' \
         > '/home/user/archive/'"$line"
done < textfile.txt
```

Anyway I haven't found a way to form the url to curl so it would work. I've tried like every possible single and double quoted versions. I've tried basically:

```
'...'"$line"'...'
"..."${line}"..."
'...'$line'...'
```

and so on.. Just name it and I'm pretty sure that I've tried it.

When I'm printing out the URL in the best case it will be formed as:

```
 /subscriptions?v=2&alt=jsoneeds/api/users/KEYWORD FROM FILE
```

or something similar. If you know what could be the cause of this I would appreciate the information. Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's not a quoting issue.  The problem is that your keyword file is in DOS format -- that is, each line ends with carriage return & linefeed (\r\n) rather than just linefeed (\n).  The carriage return is getting read into the line variable, and included in the URL.  The giveaway is that when you echo it, it appears to print:

```
/subscriptions?v=2&alt=jsoneeds/api/users/KEYWORD FROM FILE"
```

but it's really printing:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/KEYWORD FROM FILE
/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json
```

...with just a carriage return between them, so the second overwrites the first.

So what can you do about it?  Here's a fairly easy way to trim the cr at the end of the line:

```
cr=$'\r'
while read line
do
    line="${line%$cr}"
    curl "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/${line}/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json" \
         > "/home/user/archive/$line"
done < textfile.txt
```

Comment: Such an error related to `\r\n` instead of \n when using curl may occur in a case when the file used as a source when composing curl invocation URL is written by some script using output of previous `curl -v` invocation containing response/request headers in particular which are separated by CRLF (i.e. `\r\n`) as per HTTP standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3 . Of course, this can be solved by <CR> trimming as explained in the answer above.

Answer (score 27):

Your current version should work, I think. More elegant is to use a single pair of double quotes around the whole URL with the variable in `${}`:

```
"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/${line}/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json"
```

Comment: For some reason is just doesn't work it gets me a file saying "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know." and when I echo the same thing out the result is "/subscriptions?v=2&alt=jsoneeds/api/users/username" So it did read the username from the file right but somehow the url is still constructed wrongly.

Comment: @Mare: works perfectly here. That looks like an error message from YouTube, so your request did get there. Is your curl up to date?

Comment: At least if I run curl "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json" it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @Mare: try echoing the result instead of running curl to debug it.

Comment: I tried and as I mentioned it seems to left the beginning of the url away. The url should be https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json and what I get is /subscriptions?v=2&alt=json.com/feeds/api/users/username

Comment: @Mare: that's extremely strange. I'm sorry, but I have no explanation for this behavior. Did you set any bash settings to exotic values?

Comment: Thanks anyway! I didn't set anything. Maybe I'll just try run the script on my other computer tomorrow. As far as I can guess the reason seems to be with the shell if it works with others.

Comment: For me single quotes are not working, but changing them to double quotes solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, double quotes is a solution.

Comment: $ curl "only use ${variable} in the double quotes" ✅

Answer (score 7):

Just use it like this, should be sufficient enough:

```
curl "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/${line}/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json" > "/home/user/archive/${line}"
```

If your shell gives you issues with `&` just put `\&`, but it works fine for me without it.

Answer (score 1):

If the data from the file can contain spaces and you have no objection to spaces in the file name in the `/home/user/archive` directory, then what you've got should be OK.

Given the contents of the rest of the URL, you could even just write:

```
while read line
do
    curl "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/${line}/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json" \
         > "/home/user/archive/${line}"
done < textfile.txt
```

where strictly the `${line}` could be just `$line` in both places.  This works because the strings are fixed and don't contain shell metacharacters.

Since you're code is close to this, but you claim that you're seeing the keywords from the file in the wrong place, maybe a little rewriting for ease of debugging is in order:

```
while read line
do
    url="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/${line}/subscriptions?v=2&alt=json"
    file="/home/user/archive/${line}"
    curl "$url" > "$file"
done < textfile.txt
```

Since the strings may end up containing spaces, it seems (do you need to expand spaces to `+` in the URL?), the quotes around the variables are strongly recommended.  You can now run the script with `sh -x` (or add a line `set -x` to the script) and see what the shell thinks it is doing as it is doing it.

Comment: As I just commented above for some reason the reason is with the url. I just ran it with -x and the result was same it tries to get url /subscriptions?v=2&alt=json.com/feeds/api/users/username Maybe the reason is some how with my shell, I don't know what else it could be if it seems to work with everyone else.