# PHP curl request with url in variable

Tags: php, http, curl, request

I'm going crazy with this. I read some other question about it, but never found an answer.

My problem is:
I'm trying to create a PHP Curl request (GET), and the request return false if I set the url from a variable.

Here below my code:

Working code:

```
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.google.com");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Not working code:

```
$url = "www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Someone could help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: Missing `=` might be the problem, I guess, if it's your real code. It should be `$url = "www.google.com";`

Comment: `$url = "google.com"`, where is aasignment operator (=)

Comment: is your error_reporting on? Don't you get any error message? Always set error reporting on during development.

Comment: Sorry, of course there is the "="  it is a wrong cut and paste.

Comment: No, no getting error :-(

Comment: I can't replicate your issue, it works fine either way for me. If you must save the $url as a variable, have you tried passing it to the curl_init() function? Maybe that will work?

Comment: Tried also that way (passing to curl_init) same issue. I can't figure it out, it's very strange.

Comment: Look here, maybe you'll have an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865241/bash-curl-and-variable-in-the-middle-of-the-url and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341955/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-a-curl-command-in-shell-scripting. also should you add the protocol (http) to the url?

Comment: what does this code say? `var_dump('does these look the same now? '.($url==='www.google.com'?'yup':'no, they do not'),"www.google.com",$url);`

Comment: Guys thank you for your comments, at the end I figured it out. The curl request was inside a function but (for some mystical reason), the $url variable was outside, so the init was unable to see the variable content. Sorry for my stupid mistake