Run curl with token authentication in shell script (Mac)
Trying to update data from a system using curl and url/token, but I am running into the following error. I believe the way I format the curl command in the shell script is incorrect but not sure how to fix it.

curl: (3) URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function

When I run the curl command from terminal with the value, it is successful and the fields get updated.
curl -X 'PATCH' \
  'https://myurl/123' \

Ran the shell script below.
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
line='${line%$cr}'

curl -X 'PATCH' \
  'https://myurl/${line}' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer user:TOKEN' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true' \
  -d '[
  {
"path": "/field1",
"value": "10"
  },
  {
"path": "/field2",
"value": "200"
  }
]'

done < list.txt

list.txt contains

123
234
456


'https://myurl/${line}' here line won't be replaced with the variable

This question is similar to: How to use an environment variable inside a quoted string in Bash. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I referenced this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8866817

@0stone0 so should it be 'https://myurl/'${line}'' or 'https://myurl/"${line}"' ?

@0stone0 couldn't get it to work
